# Can I create an android apk file terminal in backend to execute cmd

Tags: node.js, terminal, webapp2, terminal-emulator, termux

I am a beginner in web development and I am trying to create apps just using my mobile. When I trying to create a webapp with nodejs, which basically a voice assistant I found that nodejs's built-in module (child_process) which can exicute shell script very well but the problem is it executes the cmd in where the the Index.js file was deployed in my mobile terminal, but not in the mobile who use my webapp. So I think that can I use some kind of embedded terminal which can run in backend and execute cmd in there terminal, which will work like as a android app.

I use termux as terminal.